# How do I get my code to write to the text file over a python server

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

Client Code:

```
import socket                

s = socket.socket()          
host = '127.0.0.1'           
port = 8081                  

s.connect((host, port))
s.send("Hello server!".encode('utf-8'))

with open('received_file.txt', 'w+') as f:
    print('file opened')
    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('data=%s' % data)
        if not data:
            break
        else:
            f = open('received_file.txt')
            f.write(data)

    f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

two ways to do that: either open your file in binary (note the `'b'` in the file mode) and write `bytes`:

```
with open('received_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

or decode the data to a `str` before writing:

```
with open('received_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

or use any other encoding if you are not using `utf-8`.

a side-note: in your code you have two open files called `f` (the 2nd one in the `else` part). that may not be a good idea...